# BizTalk - how to map these two nodes to a repeating node?

Tags: biztalk

I have an incoming schema that looks like this:

```
<Root>
   <ClaimDates005H>
      <Begin>20120301</Begin>
      <End>20120302</End>
   </ClaimDates005H>
</Root>
```

(there's more to it, this is just the area I'm concerned with)

I want to map it to a schema with a repeating section, so it winds up like this:

```
<Root>
   <DTM_StatementFromorToDate>
      <DTM01_DateTimeQualifier>Begin</DTM01_DateTimeQualifier>
      <DTM02_ClaimDate>20120301</DTM02_ClaimDate>
   </DTM_StatementFromorToDate>
   <DTM_StatementFromorToDate>
      <DTM01_DateTimeQualifier>End</DTM01_DateTimeQualifier>
      <DTM02_ClaimDate>20120302</DTM02_ClaimDate>
   </DTM_StatementFromorToDate>
</Root>
```

(That's part of an X12 835, BTW...)

Of course in the destination schema there's only a single occurrence of DTM_StatementFromorToDate, that can repeat... I get that I can run both Begin and End into a looping functoid to create two instances of DTM_StatementFromorToDate, one with Begin and one with End, but then how do I correctly populate DTM01_DateTimeQualifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, the Table Looping functoid took care of it.